# Lost data on geojson to topojson conversion

Tags: geojson, topojson

I grabbed a `KML` file of UK counties. I then headed over to [this other website](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) to convert the `KML` to `GeoJSON`.

All smooth so far. Then I wanted to convert the `GeoJSON` to its sibling format `TopoJSON` via the NodeJS package [topojson](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference).

So I ran the following command:

```
topojson -o topo-uk-map.json uk-map.json
```

This worked in the sense that the conversion took place, but in the process I lost all the names of the counties!!

How do I edit the command above so that the name of the counties remain in place? I looked through the documentation for *topojson* but could not find anything that would help me, either the info is not there, or the docs are not n00b friendly at all.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-p` parameter. From the Wiki (which i think is quite good actually):

> -p, --properties feature properties to preserve; no name preserves all properties

To retain some properties and rename them:

```
topojson -p newpropertyname=inputpropertyname -- input.geojson -o outpu.topojson
```

Note: topojson also accept .shp as input, which can ease your terminal work.

See: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#properties

Comment: Sorry, I was looking further up, near the example he gave up top.